# How to use flask with bootstrap3 glyphicons?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am trying to build a website using flask and bootstrap3. But i found the [glyphicons's official website](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/) says that `Copy over all the font files to a /fonts directory near your CSS.`, but after i place fonts directory at the same directory of the css file, the icon still don't appear.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try placing the `fonts/` directory adjacent to the folder containing the css.  For instance `css/` would be in the same folder as `fonts/`.

Example:

```
static/
  css/
    bootstrap-glyphicons.css
    ...
  fonts/
    glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot
    ...
  js/
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes to this, and is using Bootstrap's SASS/SCSS version, and the accepted answer doesn't help... The `_glyphicons.scss` file uses `@at-root` which only works in sass >=3.3.0. If you're using a lower version, the fonts won't load.